# Blackview recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, system-freeze, hard-reset

I have a Blackview A8 that is stuck at upgrading.
After the optimizing step (40 of 40) if just hangs and it stays like that until the battery runs out

Can anyone help me out?
I would like to go in recovery mode or to reset the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to reboot and press and hold Volume Up + Power key for about 5 seconds. When you see the Blackview logo press Power key and a menu will follow, there select recovery mode...

PS: I had to try a few times before I manage to enter the menu